# How to change Facebook share info?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried various codes and none worked.
This is one of those:

```
<?php
$title=urlencode('Title of Your iFrame Tab');
$url=urlencode('http://www.example.com/');
$summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your tab is about, or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');
$image=urlencode('http://www.daddydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/facebook_iframe_share_button.jpg');
?>

<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Insert text or an image here.</a>
```

Facebook have changed something and now the only parameter that a developer can change is the URL of the page, but nothing else.

Does anyone know if it's still possible to change the title and description of the shared page?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Facebook Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview).

The [Open Graph Protocol website](http://ogp.me).

Also there is a [plugin for Open Graph](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-open-graph/).

An example:

You can change the title and description which appears in shares with these meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description here" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The title of the page" />
```

Facebook also provides a [debugging tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) which you can use to see how it sees a given page from your website.

Sometimes Facebook seems not to clear the cache for a given page. There's a discussion about that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237980/how-to-clear-debug-tool-cache-data) on SO. I have trouble with that sometimes. For me it works puting something like `?refresh=1` at the end of the URL and then increment that number each time.

You can see a list of best practices on the use of Facebook OG [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags). Last but not least here is a [list with more available tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph). You can click on each one to see more info. I fear it is not comprehensive, though as it does not include for example `og:title`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write the answer. The thing is, from what I've seen, Facebook loads the page and then gets the meta data. However, on that page I have a quiz which returns the results with an ajax call. So I wanted to enable people to share the results on Facebook and to preset the description to something like: "I just did the X test and got 97%". However, it seems to be impossible without making a separate page for the results.

Comment: You are welcome. I found these two topics here on SO which might interest you: [OpenGraph on Ajax Based Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896773/opengraph-on-ajax-based-website) and [Facebook opengraph and AJAX content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556161/facebook-opengraph-and-ajax-content). Hope it helps. I have never tried to do something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It used to be pretty easy to manipulate the data, but Facebook have probably disabled it to some extent in order to prevent scammy websites from abusing it. Thanks once again, I really appreciate it.